# how to set POI info in settings file for the ONE simulator

Tags: settings, point-of-interest, one-simulator

I would like to include the information about 2 POIS (in the settings file) that I want the ONE simulator to take into account for simulation runs.

I know first thing is to set the following path:

PointsOfInterest.poiFile1 = data/POI.wkt

and then I'm supposed to include the indexes and probabilities but not sure exaclty how: (0, 0.3, 1, 0.7) ?

I'm not able to find any complete example of a case using POIS, can someone illustrate it? Am I missing anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer that worked:

Define POI data files

```
PointsOfInterest.poiFile1 = data/ParkPOIs.wkt
PointsOfInterest.poiFile2 = data/CentralPOIs.wkt
PointsOfInterest.poiFile3 = data/WestPOIs.wkt
PointsOfInterest.poiFile4 = data/shops.wkt
```

Define probabilities for different groups selecting POIs from different POI files

```
Group1.pois = 1,0.3, 2,0.1, 3,0.1, 4, 0.1
Group2.pois = 2,0.3, 3,0.1
Group3.pois = 3,0.3, 2,0.1, 1,0.1, 4, 0.1
Group4.pois = 4,0.3, 2,0.1, 3,0.1, 1, 0.1
```